# Accidentally removed Spotify folder, now I can't uninstall anything

Tags: command-line, apt, uninstall

I accidentally removed Spotify folder and now I can't uninstall programs from with apt-get or the Software Center, when I try to remove the flash plugin from the command line it give me this error:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.postinst: ./register.sh: not found
dpkg: error processing package spotify-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 spotify-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What to do?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get purge spotify`? That is the proper way to remove a package.

Comment: Also try to run `sudo apt-get install -f`. The package sounds like it's broken. The `-f` prefix checks all installed packages and tries to fix them.

Comment: @Ev1l0rd Yes I did try but as I said I accidentally removed a folder of Spotify so now it can't be uninstalled.

Comment: The general recommendation for such a case is to re-install the package (`--force`-fully, if necessary) with `apt-get install --reinstall` or `dpkg -i` to restore the missing files, then remove the package as usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems, that the Spotify package is still in the “configured” state, but had some of its files removed, you need to reinstall it first:

```
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall spotify-client
```

Then you should be able to uninstall it normally:

```
sudo apt-get remove spotify-client
```

Comment: I tried this and the commands didn't output any error but I still can't get rid of Spotify, `apt-get remove spotify-client` didn't work

Comment: What's the output of that command now? Still the same? If not, please add the new output to your question and give me a ping.

Answer (score 1):

Download the spotify-client deb package from the repo:

```
cd ~/Downloads && apt-get download spotify-client
```

Install it with `dpkg`

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all --no-triggers downloaded_deb
```

If it works, you will be able to remove it properly.

If it doesn't work but returns `127` error, you may need to reinstall `dpkg`, this is a tip to overcome the uncompleted installation of a package (In your case, the folder of Spotify was accidentally removed). As soon as `dpkg` is reinstalled, you redo the command `sudo dpkg -i --force-all --no-triggers downloaded_deb`.

Comment: It didn't work,  it returned error 127

Comment: Which of these command returned the error code? What was the program output? Please include your actions and findings in your original question. This makes it easier to address them properly.

Comment: @DavidFoerster [this](http://pastebin.com/TT92ySMD) is the error I get when I try the second command

Comment: @yotamN I've updated my answer. Please try it out and tell us if it works.

Comment: @TungTran Sadly reinstalling dpkg didn't work, this is the error I got: http://pastebin.com/Dfm6ReRD

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
    sudo apt-get purge spotify-client
    sudo apt-get install -f spotify-client
```

Comment: It didn't work, I can't purge spotify and the installation also failed.